# Excel - How to Compare Cells from 2 Columns then if Column B Matches, Use the Value in Column C next to the Matching Cell in Column B?

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I don't know who else to ask, so if you can help, I'd really appreciate it.

I have 4 columns:

In column A, I have an updated list of 1000 product Sku's ie. A1001 from column C.
In column B, its empty.
In column C, I have the old list of 1500 sku's
In column D, I have a name value that corresponds to the sku in column C. ie. Pita bread

Sample Data:

```
   A       B      C       D

A10897  ()  A10897  PITA

A15006  ()  A15006  CANDLE

A15008  ()  A15016  TOMATO

A15009  ()  A15017  MILK

A10900  ()  A10900  BREAD

A10901  ()  A10901  WHEAT
```

So far, I've tried 3 formulas, but its not returning the correct name.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$B$9999,1,FALSE)),"No",F2)
```

What excel formula will compare a cell in column A with column C to see if they match, and if they do, show the value of the cell in column D next to column C into cell in column B beside the matched cell in column A.

Like This:

```
   A       B      C       D

A10897  PITA    A10897  PITA

A15017  MILK    A15006  CANDLE

A10901  WHEAT   A15016  TOMATO

... (NO MATCH)  A15017  MILK

... (NO MATCH)  A10900  BREAD

... (NO MATCH)  A10901  WHEAT

etc...
```

Please help *despair*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$9999,2,0),"(NO MATCH)")
```