# Excel - need to copy a value from one column to another, if the original value exists in a different column

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I found a similar question which answered my question here:

[Excel - How to Compare Cells from 2 Columns then if Column B Matches, Use the Value in Column C next to the Matching Cell in Column B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328221/excel-how-to-compare-cells-from-2-columns-then-if-column-b-matches-use-the-va?rq=1)

I dont normally program in excel but I need to right now.  I need to check if cell A1 is in another column (Column n for example) and if it is, get the cell value of the corresponding row , in the column to the right of Column N (Column O).  and lets say the formula is placed into column P. and if the number cannot be found in column n, put a piece of text such as 'not found'.

```
Column A             Column N     Column O       Column P
1000                 1000           4556           4556
1001                 1005           4777           not found
1002                 1003           4578           not found
1003                 1007           1111           4578
```

1001 and 1002 are not found in column n so they get 'not found'  the other 2 would be found and get the corresponding values from column O.
How can I write this in excel code?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(O:O,MATCH(A1,N:N,0)),"not found")
```

Comment: thanks for your time. i actually found a similar question here, which answered my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328221/excel-how-to-compare-cells-from-2-columns-then-if-column-b-matches-use-the-va?rq=1